# Strong params requirement

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, ecmascript-6, ruby-on-rails-5

Given these strong params:

```
def image_params
  params.require(:image).permit(:data, :x, :y, :width, :height)
end
```

Exactly what should `:image` be? I'm submitting this from my front-end like so:

```
updateImage: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append(`x`, this.crop_x)
    formData.append(`y`, this.crop_y)
    formData.append(`width`, this.crop_width)
    formData.append(`height`, this.crop_height)
    formData.append(`image`, this.imageID)
    this.$http.patch(`/articles/${this.id}/images/${this.imageID}`, formData)
}
```

Here assuming `:image` should be an ID like `16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [strong_params](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) you are not necessarily specifying the type of data, you are just setting rules on which attributes are mandatory and which are permitted,

In your example, `image` is a required attribute and if it is missing in the params, you'll get an error and with `permit` for `:data, :x, :y, :width, :height` you are white-listing them so saying they are safe to use or pass through.

Rather than doing the append, you might want to create it this way,

`{image: {data: '', x: '', y: '', width: '', height: ''}}`

Hope this helps

Comment: That's also way better than the `formdata.append` stuff. Thanks!

Comment: glad to be of help, would you accept the answer if it helped you @CD-RUM